# [Android-Location]Can not get Longitude and Latitude from LocationManager

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

I used LocationManager to get user address by "Longitude" and "Latitude" but when i call location.getLongitude() and location.getLatitude(), it return 0 back to me. I manage to Google but have nobody meet my issue.

Mr.Jeremy Edwards suggest me that:

> Make sure that network based location is enabled in the phone's settings. You can detect this situation and prompt the user to enable it if you really need it.
>   I believe this is the line of code to launch this activity.

I do that but it can help. Sometime that give me Longitude and Latitude, some time not.

Here is my code:

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
```

The permission in the AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are trying it in emulator or in mobile phone? If in emulator, then DDMS settings to be enabled. If in phone, then GPS with streetlevel data settings to be enabled.

Comment: I use my Nexus 4 and i will try to enable GPS with streetlevel data settings.